# Get back QWidget after using in QItemEditorCreatorBase

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have a numeric editor that extends the `QSpinBox`

```
NumericEditor::NumericEditor(QWidget *widget): QSpinBox(widget)
```

I use this editor to edit the type `QVariant::Int` in the `QTableWidget`

```
QItemEditorCreatorBase *numericEditor = new QStandardItemEditorCreator<NumericEditor>();
factory->registerEditor(QVariant::Int, numericEditor);
```

Data is entered in the table as normal. Ignore the usage of the word "color". Its based off the color editor example.

```
QTableWidgetItem *nameItem2 = new QTableWidgetItem(QString("label2"));
QTableWidgetItem *colorItem2 = new QTableWidgetItem();
colorItem2->setData(Qt::DisplayRole, QVariant(int(4)));
table->setItem(1, 0, nameItem2);
table->setItem(1, 1, colorItem2);
```

The spin box appears and works fine in the QTableWidget.

My desire is to get access to the instance of QSpinBox that the table uses when it edits `QVariant::Int` cells so I can set the min and max values.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install a delegate on the column with `QTableWidget::setItemDelegateForColumn`, and when an editor is opened, its `createEditor` method will be called.

```
class MyDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate {
public:
    QWidget *createEditor ( QWidget * parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index ) const {
        // You could create the widget from scratch or call 
        // the base function which will use the QItemEditor you already wrote
        QWidget * editor = QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(parent, option, index);

        // do whatever you need to do with the widget
        editor->setProperty("minimum", 100);
        editor->setProperty("maximum", 100);

        return editor;
    }
};
```